# Spring boot requests updating database value around same time - 2 nodes application

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am running a springboot application on 2 nodes.

I have a scenario where requests can come in to update a column with primary key say 1234L.

Since I have 2 nodes, its possible that requests can come to each node around same time and try to update column with row Id 1234L.

What will happen in this scenario?

How such requests are handled? Do I need to implement something at service layer to take care of this? or springboot can handle it with some config?

FYI, I am not reading the updated value in my code to perform anything nor I want to rollback changes if the update fails for some reason

Comment: did you try to add [optimistic-locking](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-optimistic-locking) ?

Comment: No, I did try with @transactional annotation. we get 1000 request in 3-4 mins after sometime I started getting JDBC exceptions ,org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open JPA EntityManager for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
 at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doBegin(JpaTransactionManager.java:467)
 at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:400)

Comment: In this case, it show us that you dont reuse the connections to database, you need to check your code and find out the cause, a workaround ty to increase the `spring.datasource.hikari.maximum-pool-size=10`

Comment: I am not questioning whether using @transactional is needed as I do not have to rollback anything if update fails. Also, I am OK with dirty read as long as both requests can update db record without issues

Comment: You cannot store anything in the database without a transaction. The fact that you get that error shows you are leaking connections not using transactions isn't the solution. This is what i told you in the exact same question you asked yesterday (don't ask the same question each day, if you have additional information edit the original question instead).

Comment: I did not say I wont use transaction. I meant @Transactional annotation which is different.